# setTimeout is not staying true to the delay I give it inside a $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Given [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/VSQ4j/):

```
counter = 0;
$('div').each(function () {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter + ': Timeout is: ' + $(this).index() * 150);
    setTimeout(testTime(), $(this).index() * 150);
});

function testTime() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    console.log(counter + ': Call time is: ' + currentDate.getMilliseconds());
}
```

If you look at the console log you can see the millisecond it is called on and the supposed delay in between each call. As you can see each call is only a few milliseconds between each one.

Comment: Don't hide essential parts of your question on other websites.

Comment: If you're using `$(this).index()` to get the current index in the enumeration, you should use the first argument passed to your `.each()` callback instead. Instead of using a simple number that's already provided, you're currently *calculating* the number as the index value of `this` from among its siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to setTimeout should be a function.

You are **calling** `testTime` and passing its return value (`undefined`) as that argument.

Get rid of the `()`.

**Update in response to comments**:

If you need to pass arguments, then you need to either need to pass them in an array as the third argument (as per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)) or, for wider browser support, [use a closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/).

```
counter = 0;
$('div').each(function () {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter + ': Timeout is: ' + $(this).index() * 150);
    setTimeout(testTimeFactory(foo, bar, baz), $(this).index() * 150);
});

function testTime() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    console.log(counter + ': Call time is: ' + currentDate.getMilliseconds());
}

function testTimeFactory(a, b, c) {
    return function() {
        testTime(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to pass arguments to testTime? (Which I do in the actual context I am trying to use this in)

Comment: @ConnorBurton `setTimeout(function(){testTime(arg1, arg2, ...)}, time);`

Comment: @Connor Burton — Updated the answer.

Comment: @Neal — Since there is a loop, the odds are that whatever `arg1` and so on are, they'll change before the timer reaches zero (as they are updated for the next item in the loop).

Comment: @Quentin not if you use local variables **within** the scope of the timeout

Comment: @Neal — Err, yes … but you don't in your comment.

Comment: @Quentin thats cuz comment has very limited space in which to comment in

Answer (score 0):

In your code you were calling the function in the timeout immediately.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VSQ4j/2/
`setTimeout(testTime, $(this).index() * 150);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the call to `setTimeout`.  You need to be passing a function to the first parameter but instead you're invoking a function.  Change the call to the following

```
setTimeout(testTime, $(this).index() * 150);
```